# Manhwa about a girl who dies hitting her head, goes back in time, and marries the duke

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's a story about a girl who goes back in time and marries I think the Duke and she is the last remaining one of her family and she's made into a maid. I don't remember much else about it but I do remember that before she went back in time she had a big scar on her face and I think she died by falling and hitting her head on a rock after running away.

Comment: *The Duke of Death and His Black Maid?*

Comment: *A Tender Heart: The Story of How I Became a Duke's Maid*?

Comment: Both of the above have a scarred maid

Comment: More details would be great, even things like timing of when you read it or when it might have been released, etc.

Comment: Do you mean Manga by Manhwa? I was going to edit the title but wasn't sure.

Comment: @EtackSxchange "Manhwa" is the Korean equivalent of "Manga".

Comment: @qazmlpok Thanks. And Kawaii is a Japanese term I think

Answer (score 1):

This is *[The Predator's Fiancée](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/the-predators-fiancee)*. It is licensed by [TappyToon](https://www.tappytoon.com/en/book/the-predators-fiancee).

> Orphaned and living in a monastery, Elisha De Lauer was content and happy. That was until the De Cartiers, known for having magical abilities, came to find her. This snake-filled family forces Elisha into a slave contract with their eyes on inheriting her many assets. After years of servitude to the De Cartiers, Elisha meets a gruesome end at the hands of her captors. That would’ve been the end of her tale, but as she closed her eyes to die, she awoke again in her own past as if nothing had ever happened.

The FL is introduced as an orphan. The head of the family from the synopsis takes an interest in her as the last surviving member of her family. She is forced to sign a slavery contract and takes on a huge debt from her father. As a slave, she is tormented by her owners; the story mostly skips over this and jumps ahead to her running away, with her body already visibly scarred.

[image]

She runs and trips, hitting her head on a rock, and dies. She reincarnates in the past - after being forced into slavery, but before her body is visibly scarred.

While working as a maid, a chance encounter leads to a contract marriage with the "High General", who looks like a Duke.